# Source Control for different teams?

Tags: version-control

Need recommendations for this...

I have 2 teams

1. Enterprise SOA development with InfoPath 2003, BizTalk 2006, MSCRMv3, custom .net2 website and a bunch of webservices using VSStudio 2005 with TFS.
2. Web Team focused on public facing websites - using Adobe Suite, VSStudio 2005.

As mentioned team 1 have TFS- we dont do daily/weekly/fornight/intergration builds as we dont do that type of methodology - but we do have a custom build/test solution using msbuild plumbed into TFS.  (it does other funky things like zips for archive the version/delist biztalk, deploy new assemplies in biztalk and renelist of biztalk and a full deploy of the website and services)

Team 2 have nothing... other than a zip archive of versions.

Issues...

- TFS is expensive
- Both teams are used to the "locking school" of source control.
- need source control for differing assests

Any suggestions - OSS or other wise?

Answer (score 2):

[svn](http://subversion.tigris.org/) - can even keep your locking strategy (if you have to), also you can develop all sorts of pre/post commit hooks to automate deployments/tests etc etc. Easy to setup and manage.

Some tools & links

- [visualsvn server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server) - free
- tortoise svn - explorer add-in - free
- [visual svn](http://www.visualsvn.com) - visual studio addin ($49 per seat)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with TFS for both teams despite the expense. You have the expertise in-house already for that product and it supports the locking model you like.

If cost is a problem, go with [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) for the web team, but purchase [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) for Visual Studio integration and use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) for Explorer integration. I have found in the past that web teams tend to 'get' SVN a bit more quickly, especially with TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1):

I work with [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), running [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/), and [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and  [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) add-in for Visual Studio on client developer machines, its a really good setup, and all is OpenSource.